# How can I know keyboard language? (en/fr)

Tags: android

I develop an sms sender app and I wanna know language that user uses. so, when user types a message how can I know language that he/she uses?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/inputmethod/InputMethodManager.html#getCurrentInputMethodSubtype%28%29

Answer (score 10, accepted):

get the input type manager by using:

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
```

then , choose what to get from it using the next methods :

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/inputmethod/InputMethodManager.html#getCurrentInputMethodSubtype%28%29

or:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/inputmethod/InputMethodManager.html#getLastInputMethodSubtype()

together with this to get the locale of the input type:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/inputmethod/InputMethodSubtype.html#getLocale()

Comment: hi guy, but this solution available in API 11, and I want to use that for android 2.3! how to use your idea for lower versions before API 11.

Comment: good point. sorry for missing it . maybe it's possible to read from the android code and see if there is a way to overcome it for older versions .

Comment: Google keyboard does not return language code.. what to do about that? any solution?

Answer (score 4):

You can get keyboard language by first detecting the locale of device keyboard and then getting the `Locale` object from it. For example,

```
    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    InputMethodSubtype ims = imm.getCurrentInputMethodSubtype();
    String localeString = ims.getLocale();
    Locale locale = new Locale(localeString);
    String currentLanguage = locale.getDisplayLanguage();
```

Here, `currentLanguage` will give your keyboard language. Hope this helps.

Comment: What should we do when ims is null?

Comment: Google keyboard, Kika keyboard from Xiami does not return language code.. what to do about that? any solution?

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible to retrieve the current keyboard language. Android does not allow to retrieve the current configured language, there aren't any API.