# Keyboard - detect all languages, change language, install language

Tags: android, keyboard, locale, android-softkeyboard, android-keypad

I'm looking for a solution to these problems:

1) How to change Android Keyboard language?

2) How to detect all installed keyboard languages?

3) How to install some keyboard language?

---

Are these problems possible to do? I found some info:

Ad 1) I think this is not possible right (without permission and app has to run as a system app)? Source: [Change Keyboard input language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12303593/change-keyboard-input-language)

Ad 2) I can detect current language ([How to programmatically get current keyboard language on an Android device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16484007/how-to-programmatically-get-current-keyboard-language-on-an-android-device)) but I want to detect all installed languages. Is it possible?

Ad 3) Is this possible? Or only the user can do it? The best way what I found is open language settings with intent.

Can someone please confirm that.

Answer (score 0):

Are you going to make your own keyboard?

if yes, than you can make your Setting activity, in that you can handle all of your preferences for languages & also set current keyboard subtype.

to set Setting activity :

```
<input-method xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:settingsActivity=".yourkeyboardpackage.SettingAcitivity"/>
```

to set subtype:

```
inputMethodManager.setCurrentInputMethodSubtype( your input method subtype here)
```