# Android Emulator not showing keys on keyboard

Tags: android, android-studio, android-edittext, android-emulator, android-keypad

`Android Studio Emulator` is showing `black spots` instead of `keys` on keyboard.

Anyone knows whats the reason behind this?

[image]

Comment: I think it is a problem with your `Android Emulator` configuration. try to create a new emulator with the actual OS. Else, you can `Invalidate caches` in the `Settings` tab or, in my case,  to reinstall `Android Studio`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your input method has changed to some which is unrecognized by android OS.
You could try explicitly setting the language on keyboard in app.

Check this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16484007/how-to-programmatically-get-current-keyboard-language-on-an-android-device).

Comment: Yes, Something like that. The default keyboard was `GBoard` which was not working in the emulator but when I changed it to `Google Indic Keyboard` then it worked. Thanks @Dressy Fiddle

Comment: No problem happy to help ;)