# How can I check language in EditText?

Tags: android

I'm using 3 language(English, Korean, Japanese) in my app.

Is it possible to distinguish String the language in EditText?

Comment: It is **theoretically** possible (by scanning all the words of all languages to find a match with the EditText contents). But it would be an overkill.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A String or EditText doesn't contain information about the language, therefore you need a workaround.

*Options:*

- [Check the keyboard language.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14775529/199048)
- [Scan the String for code points](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26358371/199048) in a specific range to identify Asian languages. It won't work if they share the same character set, for example english and german.
- Implement your own solution.