# I want to detect if the keyboard input method/langaue is Arabic in Android

Tags: android, keyboard

I want to detect whether the keyboard input method/language is Arabic, and I want to use it in my Conditional Block. Like this

```
if(Keyboard input method/language is Arabic)
{
  //do something
}
```

keep in mind I just want to detect whether the keyboard input method/language is Arabic, rest of the code I will write myself.

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14775218/how-can-i-know-keyboard-language-en-fr. Check this buddy!!

Answer (score 0):

You can get Input Language as follows:

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
InputMethodSubtype ims = imm.getCurrentInputMethodSubtype();
String localeString = ims.getLocale();
Locale locale = new Locale(localeString);
String currentLanguage = locale.getDisplayLanguage();
```

Comment: Google keyboard, Kika keyboard from Xiami does not return language code.. what to do about that? any solution?

Answer (score 0):

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
InputMethodSubtype ims = imm.getCurrentInputMethodSubtype();
String localeString = ims.getLocale();
Locale locale = new Locale(localeString);
String currentLanguage = locale.getDisplayLanguage();

if(Keyboard input method.equals(currentLanguage)
    {
      //do something
    }
```

Comment: Google keyboard, Kika keyboard from Xiami does not return language code.. what to do about that? any solution?

Answer (score -2):

Use this proof statement:

```
if(Locale.getDefault().getLanguage().equals("ar")){
    //do something
}
```

Comment: Google keyboard, Kika keyboard from Xiami does not return language code.. what to do about that? any solution?